# printing to HP) LaserJet M1319f not working with 16.04

Tags: 16.04, hp, laserjet

I have installed the 3 exisiting driver that appear on the list when wanting to install the drivers.

- HP LaserJet M1319f MFP USB N8108SJ HP Fax (N8106SJ)
- HP LaserJet M1319f MFP(N8106SJ)
- HP LaserJet M1319f MFP(N8106SJ&interface=1)

These are the three that I install.  They all installed fine.
I send a print test to each one and in the print queue, it says stopped.

None of them work.  No activity on the printer showing any kind of transmission of data to it.

The printer works fine under Windows 7 and 10, so the printer is not the issue.

Any hints or ideas wold be great!

Joseph

Comment: How is your printer connected? USB cable? Over the LAN? As @N0rbert has posted below, `hplip` is your friend. I think 16.04 comes with hplip pre-installed. Try starting a terminal and running: `hp-setup` (without sudo, and not as root).

Answer (score 4):

Install `hplip-gui` package with `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` and add your MFP from here.

According to HP page it [is fully supported](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index).